# How can i get my ListBox working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to get to get a list box working correctly, which will function very much like this.

[image]

The `Available` exercises are seeded from Migrations/Configuration. I need to be able to add multiples of each exercise from `Available` to `Selected Regime`. I am using a view model to access multiple models from another project(`User` and `RegimeItems`). However im simply at a loss at what to do next.

**Controller.cs**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Exercise(int? id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        UserExerciseViewModel model = new UserExerciseViewModel { AvailableExercises = GetAllExercises(), RequestedExercises = new List<RegimeItem>() };
        return View(model);
    }

    //Post
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UserExerciseViewModel model, string add, string remove, string send, int id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        //ModelState.Clear();
        RestoreSavedState(model);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(add))
            AddExercises(model);
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(remove))

        SaveState(model);
        return View(model);
    }

    void SaveState(UserExerciseViewModel model)
    {

        model.SavedRequested = string.Join(",", model.RequestedExercises.Select(p => p.RegimeItemID.ToString()).ToArray());


        model.AvailableExercises = GetAllExercises().Except(model.RequestedExercises).ToList();
    }

    void RemoveExercises(UserExerciseViewModel model)
    {
        if (model.RequestedSelected != null)
        {
            model.RequestedExercises.RemoveAll(p => model.RequestedSelected.Contains(p.RegimeItemID));
            model.RequestedSelected = null;
        }
    }

    void AddExercises(UserExerciseViewModel model)
    {
        if (model.AvailableSelected != null)
        {
            var prods = GetAllExercises().Where(p => model.AvailableSelected.Contains(p.RegimeItemID));
            model.RequestedExercises.AddRange(prods);
            model.AvailableSelected = null;
        }
    }

    void RestoreSavedState(UserExerciseViewModel model)
    {
        model.RequestedExercises = new List<RegimeItem>();

        //get the previously stored items
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SavedRequested))
        {
            string[] prodids = model.SavedRequested.Split(',');
            var prods = GetAllExercises().Where(p => prodids.Contains(p.RegimeItemID.ToString()));
            model.RequestedExercises.AddRange(prods);
        }
    }

    public ViewResult Done()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public List<RegimeItem> GetAllExercises()
    {
        var items = db.RegimeItems.ToList();
    }
```

**UserExerciseViewModel.cs**

```
namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Models
{
    public class UserExerciseViewModel
    {
        public List<RegimeItem> AvailableExercises { get; set; }
        public List<RegimeItem> RequestedExercises { get; set; }

        public int[] AvailableSelected { get; set; }
        public int[] RequestedSelected { get; set; }
        public string SavedRequested { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Migrations/Configuration.cs**

```
protected override void Seed(FaceToFace.Model.F2FData context)
        {
var ahPose = new Pose { Name = "Ah" };
```

There are lots of other pieces of information that specify the `pose`/`Exercise` however its not relevant to the question.

**View - Exercise.cs**

```
<%using(Html.BeginForm()){ %>
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Available</th>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>Selected</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <%=Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.AvailableExercises,
                    new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailableExercises, "RegimeItemID",
                    "Name", Model.AvailableSelected))%>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <input type="submit" name="add"
                           id="add" value=">>" /><br />
                    <input type="submit" name="remove"
                           id="remove" value="<<" />
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <%=Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.RequestedSelected,
                    new MultiSelectList(Model.RequestedExercises, "RegimeItemID",
                    "Name", Model.RequestedSelected))%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <%=Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.SavedRequested) %>
</div>
<%} %>
```

What i am trying to do is allow exercises to assigned specifically to each user.  These excercises have already been seeded.  When this works correctly it should allow the exercises to accessed in a descending order.

**Update**

As per Stephens suggestions i have got the code to at least not throw any errors.

However this an image of what i am receiving on the Exercise page now.
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

As per Stephen's help i have made changes to the **Excercise.cshtml** view below.

```
@model FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.UserExerciseViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Available</th>
                        <th>
                        </th>
                        <th>Selected</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.AvailableExercises, new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailableExercises, "RegimeItemID", "RegimeExercise", Model.AvailableSelected))
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <input type="submit" name="add"
                                   id="add" value=">>" /><br />
                            <input type="submit" name="remove"
                                   id="remove" value="<<" />
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.RequestedSelected, new MultiSelectList(Model.RequestedExercises, "RegimeItemID", "RegimeExercise", Model.RequestedSelected))
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br />
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SavedRequested)
        </div>
}
```

I am now getting this as the listbox shown in the image below.

[image]

I am not sure if this problem resides in site.css however its more likely that it's not finding the exercises that have been seeded.

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with? You should use javascript/jquery to move the items to the other listbox when you click the add/remove buttons rather than submitting each time.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thankyou for your help once again. Im struggling with the view model  in the `GetAllExercises` class.  This is the first time i've attempted this and im terrible with Javascript and Jquery.  I'd like to do it that way but i wouldn't know how to.

Comment: Not sure what what you mean struggling with `GetAllExercises()`? Is it supposed to be a method which returns all exercise from a database. In any case it does not belong in a view model.

Comment: I cannot put it in the `RegimeItems` model as i cannot edit the models from that project.  I can put it in the Controller but i still don't know what it should contain to access the exercises.  If i put `RegimeItem` in there i get `'FaceToFace.Model.RegimeItem' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'`.  And yes its supposed to return the exercises from the db.

Comment: What is the code you have tried? Based on one of you previous questions your using EF, so it would just something like `var items = db.RegimeItems.ToList()` to get all `RegimeItem`'s

Comment: Thanks!, i removed the 'Static' and added your suggestion to `GetAllExercises()` . Now i am getting:

`'FaceToFaceWebsite.Controllers.PatientController.GetAllExercises()': not all code paths return a value'`

Comment: Can you edit you question and append the code you are trying. I'm still a bit unsure of what your trying to do and what problems you need to solve

Comment: OK, Have seen your edit. I meant that `var items = db.RegimeItems.ToList();` should be used directly in the controller, but since you have a helper method, change it to `return db.RegimeItems.ToList();` (and the method should be `private`, not `public`)

Comment: Thanks Stephen that has stopped errors from being thrown and it finally builds now.  I have added an image to the question to show you where i am at now.

Comment: You other questions indicated you were using Razor. Have you suddenly changed to apsx? `<%using(..` vs `@using(..`? (and you have also tagged the question as Razor)

Comment: ah i think you're right i was following a tutorial for the view but it seems ive taken a wrong turn. what should i do with the Html.ListBoxFor? i will have a dig around and see what else i can come up with.

Comment: It just needs to be `@using(Html.BeginForm())` and `@Html.ListBoxFor()` and `@Html.HiddenFor()`

Comment: Way ahead of you ;)  im getting `An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation` on `model.AvailableExercises` , `model.RequestedSelected` and `model.SavedRequested`.  If i put `UserExerciseViewModel` in place of `model` i get `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.UserExerciseViewModel.SavedRequested.get'.`

Comment: Have you declared the model at the top of the view - `@model FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.UserExerciseViewModel` ?

Comment: Ah sorry i just tried that moments before you commented.  Im getting a parsing error with `<div>` and the message is `Parser Error Message: Expected a "{" but found a "<".  Block statements must be enclosed in "{" and "}".  You cannot use single-statement control-flow statements in CSHTML pages.`

Comment: apologies, disregard the last message. I missed my squiggly brackets.

Comment: I have updated the question with whats happening now, would this be a problem in site.css or is it not finding the Exercises?

Comment: Looks like a css issue. Check the widths of the tables `th` and `td` elements using your browser tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Stephens help i was able to get it to work, on the other hand it appears that im using one of the models incorrectly.Stephen has provided the information that got me to a error-less build, regardless of my failings before i posted the question.  The final issue is not with css as mentioned in the comments, well it might be but the problem before that is that the are multiple models i need to use to get the exercises to show.

This is the viewmodel.

```
namespace FaceToFaceWebsite.Models

    {
        public class UserExerciseViewModel
        {
            public List<RegimeItem> AvailableExercises { get; set; }
            public List<RegimeItem> RequestedExercises { get; set; }

            public int[] AvailableSelected { get; set; }
            public int[] RequestedSelected { get; set; }
            public string SavedRequested { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

Controller.cs

```
    //GET
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Exercise(int? id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        UserExerciseViewModel model = new UserExerciseViewModel { AvailableExercises = GetAllExercises(), RequestedExercises = new List<RegimeItem>() };
        return View(model);
    }

    //Post
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UserExerciseViewModel model, string add, string remove, string send, int id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        //ModelState.Clear();
        RestoreSavedState(model);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(add))
            AddExercises(model);
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(remove))

        SaveState(model);
        return View(model);
    }

    void SaveState(UserExerciseViewModel model)
    {

        model.SavedRequested = string.Join(",", model.RequestedExercises.Select(p => p.RegimeItemID.ToString()).ToArray());


        model.AvailableExercises = GetAllExercises().Except(model.RequestedExercises).ToList();
    }

    void RemoveExercises(UserExerciseViewModel model)
    {
        if (model.RequestedSelected != null)
        {
            model.RequestedExercises.RemoveAll(p => model.RequestedSelected.Contains(p.RegimeItemID));
            model.RequestedSelected = null;
        }
    }

    void AddExercises(UserExerciseViewModel model)
    {
        if (model.AvailableSelected != null)
        {
            var prods = GetAllExercises().Where(p => model.AvailableSelected.Contains(p.RegimeItemID));
            model.RequestedExercises.AddRange(prods);
            model.AvailableSelected = null;
        }
    }

    void RestoreSavedState(UserExerciseViewModel model)
    {
        model.RequestedExercises = new List<RegimeItem>();

        //get the previously stored items
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SavedRequested))
        {
            string[] prodids = model.SavedRequested.Split(',');
            var prods = GetAllExercises().Where(p => prodids.Contains(p.RegimeItemID.ToString()));
            model.RequestedExercises.AddRange(prods);
        }
    }

    public ViewResult Done()
    {
        return View();
    }

    private List<RegimeItem> GetAllExercises()
    {
        return db.RegimeItems.ToList();
    }
```

and the View.

```
@model FaceToFaceWebsite.Models.UserExerciseViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Available</th>
                        <th>
                        </th>
                        <th>Selected</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.AvailableExercises, new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailableExercises, "RegimeItemID", "RegimeExercise", Model.AvailableSelected))
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <input type="submit" name="add"
                                   id="add" value=">>" /><br />
                            <input type="submit" name="remove"
                                   id="remove" value="<<" />
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.RequestedSelected, new MultiSelectList(Model.RequestedExercises, "RegimeItemID", "RegimeExercise", Model.RequestedSelected))
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br />
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SavedRequested)
        </div>
}
```